# cloning an entire div tag on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i Want to clone an entire div tag every time the ADD MORE button is clicked.. I tried but its not working.

**html**

```
 <div id="student" class="row"><br/><br/>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Firstname</label>
                  <label style="color:red;" id="std_first_name_error"></label>
                  <div class="append-icon">
                      <input type="text" id="std_first_name" name="std_first_name1" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter first name" minlength="4" maxlength="16" required>
                      <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Select School</label>
                  <label style="color:red;" id="std_scl_error"></label>
                  <div class="option-group">
                    <select id="std_scl_name" name="std_scl_name" class="language" required>
                      <option value="">Select school..</option>

                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <button id="add_student" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary">Add More</button>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){       
            var count = 2;
            $('#add_student').click (function(e){
                e.preventDefault()
                var clonedEl = $('#student').first().clone()
                clonedEl.find(':text').attr('name','std_first_name'+count)
            });
            });
    </script>
```

**Application**

[image]

Comment: I recommend you to delimit js lines with semicolon `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a div to contain all students

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="student" class='row'>--Your old stuff here</div>
</div>
```

And change something in the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        var count = 2;
        $('#add_student').click (function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var clonedEl = $('#student').first().clone();
            clonedEl.find(':text').attr('name','std_first_name'+count);
            //Add the newly div the the entire div
            $('#all').append(clonedEl);
    });
});
```